# Do not consider square brackets as charater class while replacing in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am using javascript's replace function.

```
string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)
```

This is the syntax and from what I understand searchvalue can be a regular expression. How do I handle the case when my searchvalue contains square brackets but it shouldn't be considered as a character class?

Example:

```
seachvalue = abc[xyz]def
newvalue = abcabc[xyz]defdef
string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)
```

When I try to use this, it gives me an error because it is considering [xyz] in searchvalue as character class. How do I specify that it is not so?

P.S Other questions related to this are more to do with the content within brackets.

Comment: Escape the literal string that will be used as (part of) regex.

Comment: Try: seachvalue = 'abc\[xyz\]def' that should work